# Javascriptissexy Quizzer Solution

Tags: javascript, quiz

I built a JavaScript quizzer as a project from [javascriptissexy](http://javascriptissexy.com/), I haven't added the improvements that they suggested. But I wanted to ask if I am doing this right, to be honest I am not really confident to what I did as I am sure there is more efficient way to do the things required.

I wanted to avoid much of repetition and I want to know if I actually did or just made it worst because I think it's important to know that before I proceed to more stuff?

```js
var Allquestions = [{
        question: "Who is naruto's father?",
        choices: ["Jiraiya", "Sarutobi", "Orichimaru", "Minato"],
        answer: 3

    },
    {
        question: "Why did sasuke left konoha?",
        choices: ["To avenge his clan by killing his brother", "To train and surpass naruto", "To join the akatsuki", "To cast tsukuyomi upon the world"],
        answer: 0

    },
    {
        question: "In shippuden series how did naruto found out about his father?",
        choices: ["Jiraiya being restored by edo tensei", "Naruto almost ripping the 9 tails seal", "Naruto on brink of his death", "Pain telling him who's his father is"],
        answer: 1
    },
    {
        question: "Who founded the Akatsuki?",
        choices: ["Nagato", "Pain", "Yahiko", "Obito/tobi"],
        answer: 2
    },
    {
        question: "When did the term 'Legendary Sannins' was coined?",
        choices: ["During the First Shinobi World War", "During the Second Shinobi World War", "During the third Shinobi World War", "During the Fourth Great Ninja War"],
        answer: 1
    },
    {
        question: "Besides Might guy father Might duy, who else is dubbed as 'Eternal Genin'?",
        choices: ["Naruto Uzumaki", "Kosuke Maruboshi", "Tobirama Senju", "Chōji Akimichi"],
        answer: 1
    },
    {
        question: "Was naruto able to control his jinjuriki during the pain attack?",
        choices: ["Yes, his father helped him", "Yes, he trained at Mount Myōboku to control the 9 tails power", "No, he wasnt able to control the 9 tails power", "No, he wasnt able to control the 9 tails but he became friend with kurama"],
        answer: 2
    },
    {
        question: "Kakashi's father Sakumo Hatake is renowned across the shinobi world as Konoha's White Fang, what is Kakashis famous title?",
        choices: ["Copy Ninja Kakashi", "Kakashi the Sharingan", "New White Fang", "Konoha's Yellowflash"],
        answer: 1
    }
];

// GLOBAL SCOPE //
var answersArr = []; // STORED ANSWERS //
var countPage = 1; // FAKE PAGE DEFAULT VALUE //
var alreadyAnswered = false; // UNIQUE ANSWER VALIDATION //
var page = 0; // INDEX PAGE DEFAULT VALUE //
var textNode = ""; // QUESTION TEXT DEFAULT VALUE //
var msgbox = "#info-msg";
var currentScore = "#info-score";
var score = 0; // COUNT CORRECT ANSWER //
var indexController = 0; // INDEX DEFAULT VALUE //
// READY AND CALL //
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(msgbox).empty();
    createQuiz(page); //CREATE QUESTION DEFAULT // 
    $("#navigate").on('click', function() {
        validateAnswer(); //VALIDATE ANSWER BEFORE PROCEEDING//
    });
    $("#submit").on('click', function(){
        checkAnswer(); //LET'S CHECK ANSWERS //
    })
})

// FUNCTIONS //
function createQuiz(crPage) {
    // CURRENT INDEX QUESTION //
    textNode = Allquestions[indexController].question;
    switch (crPage) {
        case 0:
            appendQuestion() //APPEND CURRENT QUESTION//
            appendChoices() //APPEND CORRESPONDING CHOICES//
            break;
        case 1:
            appendQuestion()
            appendChoices()
            break;
        case 2:
            appendQuestion()
            appendChoices()
            break;
        case 3:
            appendQuestion()
            appendChoices()
            break;
        case 4:
            appendQuestion()
            appendChoices()
            break;
        case 5:
            appendQuestion()
            appendChoices()
            break;
        case 6:
            appendQuestion()
            appendChoices()
            break;
        case 7:
            appendQuestion()
            appendChoices()
        default:
            // code

    }
}


function checkAnswer(){
    var i;
    var ar = answersArr.length;
    for(i=0; i < ar; i++){
        if(answersArr[i] === Allquestions[i].choices[Allquestions[i].answer]){ //CHECK IF ANSWER IS CORRECT//
            score += 5; //ADD +5 ON EVERY CORRECT ANSWER//
        }
    }
    $(currentScore).html("SCORE :" + score); // SHOW OUR SCORE//
    answersArr = [];
}
function validateAnswer() {
    var inputElem = $("input[name=answer]:checked"); //GET SELECTED ANSWER//
    if (inputElem.val() !== undefined) { //PROCEED//
        answersArr.push(inputElem.val()); //LETS PUSH THE ANSWER TO OUR ARRAY //
        if (page >= 7) {
            $("#submit").css("display","block"); // LAST PAGE, CHECK ANSWER //
            $("#navigate").css("display","none"); //HIDE NEXT BTN//
        }
        else {
        page += 1; // INCREMENT OUR PAGE COUNT //
        indexController = page; //INDEX EQUALS TO CURRENT PAGE // 
        createQuiz(page); // UPDATE QUIZ //
        updateDomPage(countPage); // LETS UPDATE PAGE COUNT //
        }
    }
    else {
        $(msgbox).html("You can't do that!").fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(200);//SHOW MESSAGE//
    }

}

// UPDATE PAGE COUNT //
function updateDomPage(val) {
    val = countPage += 1;
    var pageHTML = $("#currentPage"); //GET ELEMENT THAT HOLD FAKE QUESTION COUNT//
    pageHTML.html(val);
  
}
// APPEND QUESTION CHOICES BASED ON QUESTION INDEX //
function appendChoices() {
    $("#choices").empty(); // REMOVE EXISTING CHOICES //
    var i;
    var al = Allquestions[indexController].choices.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < al; i++) {
        //console.log(Allquestions[indexController].choices[i]); // TEST ACCESS
        $("#choices").append("<input class='radiobtn' type='radio' id='" + indexController + "' name='answer' value='" + Allquestions[indexController].choices[i] + "'>") //CREATE RADIO BUTTON WITH ID/VALUE BASE ON INDEX//
        $("#choices").append("<label for='" + indexController + "'>" + Allquestions[indexController].choices[i] + "</label>") // CREATE LABEL CHOICES REPRESENTATION //
        continue;

    }
}
// APPEND QUESTIONS BASED ON INDEX //
function appendQuestion() {
    $('legend').empty() // REMOVE EXISTING TEXTNODES // 
        .append(textNode); // APPEND CURRENT INDEX TEXTNODES //
}
```

```css
*{
    font-family: 'Gloria Hallelujah', cursive;
}
div.container{
    max-width: 550px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.info{
    background: #FF7739;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height:30px;
}
div#info-msg{
    display: none;
    background: red;
    clear:both;
}
#question-wrapper{
    background: #083A85;
}
legend{
    color: #ff7609;
}
label{
    color: #AAA3AD;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- HTML5 Hello world by kirupa - http://www.kirupa.com/html5/getting_your_feet_wet_html5_pg1.htm -->
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/main.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css" type="text/css" />
<title>Hello...</title>

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
   <div class="info">
       <div id="info-score" style="float:left;font-size:13px;">
           SCORE: 0
       </div>
       <div id="info-msg">
       test message
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="quiz-box">
    <div id="question-wrapper">
        <fieldset>
            <legend> </legend>
            <div id="choices">
            
            </div>
        </fieldset>
     </div>
    </div>
<p><span id="currentPage">1</span> out of 8 questions</p>
</div>

<button id="navigate">Next</button>
<button id="submit" style="display:none">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Scoring

You always show the score on top of the questions - but you only calculate it once after all questions are answered.

From a UX point of view I would say you have two options:

**Show the score all the time**

In this case you should update it after each answer and include a feedback, so that it is clear why the score didn't change:

> Correct answer +5 points
>   Sorry, that's not correct.

**Show the score not until the final question**

Just show the score after the user hits submit. In this case the user will still not know which answers were correct and which weren't. So a summary would be nice.

---

Also the function should be called `checkAnswers()` instead of `checkAnswer()`. I was wondering why you run through all answers, when you - looking at the function's name - try to check only one.

---

## Cache DOM-elements

Instead of expensive re-querying of DOM-elements, you should get them once and store them in variables:

```
const buttonNext = $("#navigate");

buttonNext.click();
buttonNext.hide();
```

---

## Redundant code

Take a look at `createQuiz()`:

> ```
> switch (crPage) {
>     case 0:
>         appendQuestion() //APPEND CURRENT QUESTION//
>         appendChoices() //APPEND CORRESPONDING CHOICES//
>         break;
>     case 1:
>         appendQuestion()
>         appendChoices()
>         break;
> ```

No matter what value `crPage` holds, you call the exact same functions. So this could simply be:

```
function createQuiz(crPage) {
    textNode = Allquestions[indexController].question;
    appendQuestion();
    appendChoices();
}
```

---

## Changing CSS using JavaScript

Try to decouple your CSS and JavaScript as much as possible.

> ```
> $("#submit").css("display","block");
> ```

Instead use a CSS class that you toggle:

```
buttonSubmit.addClass('is-active');
```

The main advantage is, that the JavaScript isn't aware of the appearance of the element. Now you can easily change this:

```
.is-active {
    display: block
}
```

to a fade in:

```
.is-active {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

---

## HTML

To make you code valid, keep in mind, that form control elements like `input|fieldset` must be inside a `form`-element or must be referenced using the `form`-attribute.

You could simply change this element:

> ```
> <div id="question-wrapper"></div>
> ```

to

```
<form id="question-wrapper"></form>
```

Also a `button` is a `submit`-button by default. Spend them the `type`-attribute and attach them to you form as well:

```
<button id="navigate" type="button" form="question-wrapper">Next</button>
```

---

## CSS

Precedences can get tricky in large project. Try to avoid id-selector and don't put an element-selector before an id-selector.

> div#info-msg{}

Better use classes instead like:

```
.info-msg {}
```